# How to authenticate using Active Directory in SvelteKit app?

Tags: oauth, active-directory, svelte, adfs, sveltekit

I'm currently developing a SvelteKit app that needs to be available only to users in Active Directory on my server. I'm having trouble finding a package or anything at all to guide me. Could anyone help me please? :D